# Uncaught TypeError: router.afterEach is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Trying to use this demo application:
https://github.com/skyronic/vue-spa

to start a Vuex project but I'm gettig this error Uncaught TypeError: router.afterEach is not a function

relating to vuex-router-sync.

Can anyone help because I cannot find anything online.

My main.js entry point is:

```
import App from './pages/App'
import router from './router'
import store from './vuex/store'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'

sync(store, router)

router.start(App, '#app')
```

I am not actually calling the router.afterEach fucntion from within my example but it is used by the vuex-router-sync package. Sorry I'm not knowledgeable enough to pin point this in more detail.

The function is called by the package on line 25 https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync/blob/master/index.js

Thanks for everyone's help so far :)

Comment: Show your code, how are you using `vuex-router-sync`?

Comment: Where are you referencing `router.afterEach`?

Comment: I clone and run but there is no error???

Comment: Issue resolved. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by the vendor. https://github.com/skyronic/vue-spa/issues/2

Updates were made to the code base.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my project it's all ok, running without any error, and in some update it's appear. I solvented with an empty function, example of my app.js.

```js
const router = require("./../public/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js");
const routes = require("./../public/js/fos_js_routes.json");

router.afterEach = (to, from) => {
    // you code here some action
    console.log('* afterEach')
};

router.setRoutingData(routes);
```